# What are the command line options of Genymotion's player

Tags: android-emulator, command-line, genymotion

Can someone give me a list of the cli options of Genymotion's player command.  I see that I can get a  list of the devices via VituralBox's command:

```
$ VBoxManage list vms
```

Then I can start the desired device with:

```
$ ./player --vm-name "Samsung Galaxy S2 - 2.3.7 - API 10 - 480x800"
```

Now I'm looking for player command option to start the Genymotion from the last run state.  In other words have it resume where it was when the device was closed.

There's a chance the option might be in one of the possible cli arguments.  I've searched for a list, but so far my results are to how to start a VMS but not the full list of options that are available.

I also used `-help` and `--help` as a parameter, but it just gives and error.  Not the full usage options of the player command.

This is the list that I have compiled so far (found by running player without argument):

```
--vm-name
--quiet
```

It may be that those are the only options of the player command.  If it is I'd appreciate knowing so that I can stop searching.

Answer (score 1):

When you use player inproperely it writes help info into the log file. Eg.

```
siciarek@siciarek ~ $ ~/bin/genymotion/player --help
Logging activities to file: /home/siciarek/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
siciarek@siciarek ~ $ tail -n 6 /home/siciarek/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
2018-01-18T18:28:13+01:00 [:8281] [debug] Usage: player
2018-01-18T18:28:13+01:00 [:8281] [debug]        --vm-name|-n <device name>
2018-01-18T18:28:13+01:00 [:8281] [debug]        [ --no-popup|-s ]
2018-01-18T18:28:13+01:00 [:8281] [debug]        [ --poweroff|-x  || 
2018-01-18T18:28:13+01:00 [:8281] [debug]          --startadb|-a  || 
2018-01-18T18:28:13+01:00 [:8281] [debug]          --stopadb|-z ]
siciarek@siciarek ~ $
```